# MenuBar like behaviour in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I want to have menubar like behaviour when clicked on a rectangle. Whenever a rectangle is clicked a model is updated and a `ListView` is shown. I want this `ListView` to disappear whenever another `Rectangle` is clicked and the listmodel should not be appended with each click. Here is my sample code.

**Card.qml**

```
Rectangle {
    id: card
    width: 50
    height: 100
    color: "pink"
    Item {
        id: rec
        width: 50
        anchors.bottom: parent.top

        ListModel {
            id: menuListModel
        }

        Component {
            id: delegate
            Rectangle {
                width: 50
                height: 20
                color: "blue"
                Text {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    text: commandText
                }
            }
        }

        ListView {
            anchors.fill: parent
            model:menuListModel
            delegate: delegate
            interactive: false
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            rec.height += 40;
            menuListModel.append({"commandText" : "Act"});
            menuListModel.append({"commandText" : "Set"});
        }
    }
}
```

**main.qml**

```
Item {
    width: 120
    height: 200
    Row {
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        spacing: 10
        Card {
            id: card1
        }
        Card {
            id: card2
        }
    }
}
```

Also I want to call certain function upon clicking menu buttons i.e. `Act` and `Set`.

**Edit**

The following function is called with appropriate flags when a card(here rectangle) is clicked.

```
property int command_activate:  0x0001
property int command_summon:    0x0002
property int command_spsummon:  0x0004
property int command_mset:      0x0008
property int command_sset:      0x0010
property int command_repos:     0x0020
property int command_attack:    0x0040
property int command_list:      0x0080

function showMenu(flag) {
    if(flag & command_activate) {
        rec.height += 15;
        menuListModel.append({"commandText" : "Activate"});
    }
    if(flag & command_summon) {
        rec.height += 15;
        menuListModel.append({"commandText" : "Normal Summon"});
    }
    if(flag & command_spsummon) {
        rec.height += 15;
        menuListModel.append({"commandText" : "Special Summon"});
    }
    if(flag & command_mset) {
        rec.height += 15;
        menuListModel.append({"commandText" : "Set"});
    }
    if(flag & command_sset) {
        rec.height += 15;
        menuListModel.append({"commandText" : "Set"});
    }
    if(flag & command_repos) {
        if(position & pos_facedown) {
            rec.height += 15;
            menuListModel.append({"commandText" : "Flip Summon"});
        }
        else if(position & pos_attack) {
            rec.height += 15;
            menuListModel.append({"commandText" : "To Defense"});
        }
        else {
            rec.height += 15;
            menuListModel.append({"commandText" : "To Attack"});
        }
    }
    if(flag & command_attack) {
        rec.height += 15;
        menuListModel.append({"commandText" : "Attack"});
    }
    if(flag & command_list) {
        rec.height += 15;
        menuListModel.append({"commandText" : "View"});
    }
}
```

So, in short when a card is clicked a menu has to be shown according to the `flag` on the top of the card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

You cannot name your `delegate` "delegate". When you do this, the `ListView` uses its own delegate property to set itself, leading to nothing happening.

Also, why don't you just statically fill your `ListView` then use the `visible` property to toggle whether you display it or not? If you want it to disappear whenever another `Card` is clicked, you may have to use the `focus` property.

Indeed, setting focus to true will reset the focus of all other Items within the focus scope. Something like this might work:

```
Rectangle {
    id: card
    ...
    property alias model: list.model

    Component {
        id: mydelegate
        Rectangle {
            width: 50
            height: 20
            ...
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: list
        visible: card.activeFocus
        anchors.bottom: parent.top
        width: card.width
        delegate: mydelegate
        interactive: false
        height: childrenRect.height
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            card.focus = !card.focus
        }
    }
}
```

As for calling a function, you could add the name of the function to call directly in the `ListModel`. Add a `MouseArea` in your delegate, and send a signal on clicked. Then, you just have to call the matching slot (Agreed, the `this[slot]()` syntax is a bit hacky).

**In Card.qml**

```
Rectangle {
    id: card
    ...

    property alias model: list.model
    signal itemClicked(string slot)

    Component {
        id: mydelegate
        Rectangle {
            ...
            MouseArea
            {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    if(model.slot)
                        itemClicked(slot)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

**In main.qml**

```
    ...
    Card
    {
        model: ListModel {
            ListElement{commandText: "Act"; slot: "act"}
            ListElement{commandText: "Set"; slot: "set"}
        }

        function act()
        {
           print("act triggered")
        }

        function set()
        {
           print("set trigggered")
        }

        onItemClicked: { this[slot]() }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Using `delegate` as `id` was a poor judgement from my side. I'm can't   fill my `ListView` statically because there are many button like `Act`, `Set`, `Summon` etc and visibility of each one is decided in a function. So it's a dynamic model.

Comment: Could you provide further information on how the visibility is decided? Maybe edit your answer with a code sample

Answer (score 0):

As I can't comment, to ask for clarification, I will state my assumptions from what I understood:

You have a number of `ListModel` that contain the information of the menu that should pop up, when clicking on the corresponding rectangle item in the bar.
The ListView that pops up shall disappear, once you clicked any other rectangle in this bar. (Also: if something outside the bar or menu is clicked? Or an item in the bar is selected?)

I'd go with only one ListView, and update/change the model, as well as the position (e.g. margin) once a button is clicked, so you don't have multiple unused objects flying around.
To not show anything, I think it is sufficient, to set an empty model.

You can also have a list of functions.

```
Row {
    id: row
    property var f: [a, b, c]
    function a() { console.log('a'); }
    function b() { console.log('b'); }
    function c() { console.log('c'); }
    width: 300
    height: 50
    Repeater {
        id: rep
        anchors.fill: parent
        delegate: button
        model: 3
        Rectangle {
            id: button
            width: 98
            height: 50
            border.color: 'black'
            Text {
                text: "a"
                anchors.fill: parent
            }
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: row.f[index]()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

e.g. will call the function a, b, or c - depending on the index of the rectangle.

I hope, so far, I could help.